Vega Lite - Create totals on grouped level
I'm trying to create a matrix grouped on the column 'Product'. As row headers I use the column 'column' and as column headers I use the column 'YearMonthText'. The values that are shown in my matrix comes from the column '_Value'.
I want to create totals based on my row header 'Column' so that it sums the Forecast per Product and if possible an average of the Percentage per Product (don't know if possible to use a different aggregation)

Here is my code:
{
"data": {
    "values": [
      {"Customer": "Kevin N.V.", "Product": "PH114", "YearMonthText": "2024.01", "Column": "Forecast", "_Value": 24},
      {"Customer": "Kevin N.V.", "Product": "PH114", "YearMonthText": "2024.01", "Column": "Percentage", "_Value": 0.90},
      {"Customer": "Kevin N.V.", "Product": "PH114", "YearMonthText": "2024.02", "Column": "Forecast", "_Value": 74},
      {"Customer": "Kevin N.V.", "Product": "PH114", "YearMonthText": "2024.02", "Column": "Percentage", "_Value": 0.75},
      {"Customer": "Kevin N.V.", "Product": "PH878", "YearMonthText": "2024.01", "Column": "Forecast", "_Value": 744},
      {"Customer": "Kevin N.V.", "Product": "PH878", "YearMonthText": "2024.01", "Column": "Percentage", "_Value": 0.05},
      {"Customer": "Kevin N.V.", "Product": "PH878", "YearMonthText": "2024.02", "Column": "Forecast", "_Value": 4},
      {"Customer": "Kevin N.V.", "Product": "PH878", "YearMonthText": "2024.02", "Column": "Percentage", "_Value": 0.07},
      {"Customer": "Klaas N.V.", "Product": "PH200", "YearMonthText": "2024.01", "Column": "Forecast", "_Value": 77},
      {"Customer": "Klaas N.V.", "Product": "PH200", "YearMonthText": "2024.01", "Column": "Percentage", "_Value": 0.65},
      {"Customer": "Klaas N.V.", "Product": "PH200", "YearMonthText": "2024.02", "Column": "Forecast", "_Value": 80},
      {"Customer": "Klaas N.V.", "Product": "PH200", "YearMonthText": "2024.02", "Column": "Percentage", "_Value": 0.8},
      {"Customer": "Klaas N.V.", "Product": "PH527", "YearMonthText": "2024.01", "Column": "Forecast", "_Value": 4},
      {"Customer": "Klaas N.V.", "Product": "PH527", "YearMonthText": "2024.01", "Column": "Percentage", "_Value": 0.77},
      {"Customer": "Klaas N.V.", "Product": "PH527", "YearMonthText": "2024.02", "Column": "Forecast", "_Value": 88},
      {"Customer": "Klaas N.V.", "Product": "PH527", "YearMonthText": "2024.02", "Column": "Percentage", "_Value": 0.9}
    ]
  },
  "facet": {
    "row": {
      "field": "Product",
      "title": null,
      "header": {"labelFontSize": 14}
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "layer": [
      {"mark": {"type": "rect"}},
      {
        "mark": {
          "type": "text",
          "fontSize": 12
        },
        "encoding": {
          "y": {
            "field": "Column",
            "title": null
          },
          "x": {
            "field": "YearMonthText",
            "title": null,
            "axis": {"orient": "top"}
          },
          "text": {
            "field": "_Value",
            "type": "quantitative"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Totals",
        "transform": [
          {
            "aggregate": [
              {
                "op": "sum",
                "field": "_Value",
                "as": "_New_Value"
              }
            ],
            "groupby": [
              "Product",
              "Column"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "mark": {
          "type": "text",
          "align": "right",
          "fontSize": 16,
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "x": 200,
          "color": "black"
        },
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "Column",
            "type": "nominal",
            "axis": {"title": null}
          },
          "text": {
            "field": "_New_Value_Formatted",
            "type": "nominal"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "resolve": {
    "axis": {
      "x": "independent",
      "y": "independent"
    }
  }
}

As soon as I add my 'calculate' for the formatting" inside my 'transform', I get an error stating:
         {
        "calculate": "if( datum['Column'] == 'Percentage', format( datum['_New_Value'], '.0%'), if( datum['Column'] == 'Forecast', format( datum['_New_Value'], ',.0f'), format( datum['_New_Value'], ',.0f')",
        "as": "_New_Value_Formatted"
      }


Is there anyone who can help me solve this problem?
Thank you!

try this:
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Customer": "Kevin N.V.",
        "Product": "PH114",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.01",
        "Column": "Forecast",
        "_Value": 24
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Kevin N.V.",
        "Product": "PH114",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.01",
        "Column": "Percentage",
        "_Value": 0.9
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Kevin N.V.",
        "Product": "PH114",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.02",
        "Column": "Forecast",
        "_Value": 74
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Kevin N.V.",
        "Product": "PH114",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.02",
        "Column": "Percentage",
        "_Value": 0.75
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Kevin N.V.",
        "Product": "PH878",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.01",
        "Column": "Forecast",
        "_Value": 744
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Kevin N.V.",
        "Product": "PH878",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.01",
        "Column": "Percentage",
        "_Value": 0.05
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Kevin N.V.",
        "Product": "PH878",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.02",
        "Column": "Forecast",
        "_Value": 4
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Kevin N.V.",
        "Product": "PH878",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.02",
        "Column": "Percentage",
        "_Value": 0.07
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Klaas N.V.",
        "Product": "PH200",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.01",
        "Column": "Forecast",
        "_Value": 77
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Klaas N.V.",
        "Product": "PH200",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.01",
        "Column": "Percentage",
        "_Value": 0.65
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Klaas N.V.",
        "Product": "PH200",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.02",
        "Column": "Forecast",
        "_Value": 80
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Klaas N.V.",
        "Product": "PH200",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.02",
        "Column": "Percentage",
        "_Value": 0.8
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Klaas N.V.",
        "Product": "PH527",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.01",
        "Column": "Forecast",
        "_Value": 4
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Klaas N.V.",
        "Product": "PH527",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.01",
        "Column": "Percentage",
        "_Value": 0.77
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Klaas N.V.",
        "Product": "PH527",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.02",
        "Column": "Forecast",
        "_Value": 88
      },
      {
        "Customer": "Klaas N.V.",
        "Product": "PH527",
        "YearMonthText": "2024.02",
        "Column": "Percentage",
        "_Value": 0.9
      }
    ]
  },
  "facet": {
    "row": {"field": "Product", "title": null, "header": {"labelFontSize": 14}}
  },
  "spec": {
    "width": {"step": 60},
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": {
          "type": "rect",
          "color": "#2A6AC8",
          "cornerRadius": 5,
          "stroke": "#ffffff",
          "strokeWidth": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "text", "fontSize": 12, "color": "#ffffff"},
        "encoding": {
          "y": {
            "field": "Column",
            "title": null,
            "axis": {
              "grid": false,
              "domain": false,
              "ticks": false,
              "offset": 5
            }
          },
          "x": {
            "field": "YearMonthText",
            "title": null,
            "axis": {
              "orient": "top",
              "grid": false,
              "domain": false,
              "ticks": false,
              "offset": 3,
              "labelAngle": 0
            }
          },
          "text": {"field": "_Value", "type": "quantitative"}
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Totals",
        "transform": [
          {
            "aggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "_Value", "as": "_New_Value"}],
            "groupby": ["Product", "Column"]
          },
          {
            "calculate": "datum.Column === 'Percentage' ? format( datum._New_Value, '.0%') : datum.Column === 'Forecast' ? format( datum._New_Value, ',.0f') : format( datum._New_Value, ',.0f')",
            "as": "_New_Value_Formatted"
          }
        ],
        "mark": {
          "type": "text",
          "align": "left",
          "fontSize": 14,
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "dx": 70,
          "color": "black"
        },
        "encoding": {
          "y": {"field": "Column", "title": null},
          "text": {"field": "_New_Value_Formatted", "type": "nominal"}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "resolve": {"axis": {"x": "independent", "y": "independent"}},
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}}
}


Thanks, that looks good already. There's just a small issue and that is that I get an extra label in my column header 'YearMonthText' named 'undefined'? Any reason why?

Spec above is updated. Please mark this as solved if it works fine.

Thank you for the answer and for the additional formatting, looks great! I still have a lot to learn about Vega-lite.
